# How can I reference the ObjectFactory class generated by xjc from within my xjc plugin code?

Tags: java, xjc

Ideally I would like to add some generated code to the ObjectFactory class. If that is not possible I would like to use the generated ObjectFactory as a parameter in another generated method.

This scenario would look something like this:

```
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.Outline;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.ClassOutline;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMethod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;

public class App extends Plugin {
    ...
    private static void generateMyMethod(Outline model, ClassOutline classOutline) {
        //somehow get 'objectFactoryInstance'
        JMethod method = classOutline.implClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC | JMod.FINAL | JMod.STATIC, Void.class, "useObjectFactory")
                .param(objectFactoryInstance, "input"));
    }
}
```

and the generated code should look like this:

```
public final static void useObjectFactory(ObjectFactory input) {
    //stuff happens here
}
```

**The question is how can I reach the generated ObjectFactory from within my XJC Plugin?**

The other generated classes are accessible like this, except the ObjectFactory:

```
@Override
public boolean run(Outline model, Options opt, ErrorHandler errorHandler) throws SAXException {
    for (ClassOutline classOutline : model.getClasses()) {
        //do something with the generated class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to access the generated ObjectFactory class like I accessed the other generated classes. So now I'm generating code that assumes that the ObjectFactory will be generated. Based on that assumption I create another class with the method I wanted.

```
import com.sun.codemodel.JBlock;
import com.sun.codemodel.JExpr;
import com.sun.codemodel.JExpression;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMethod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JVar;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.ClassOutline;

//...
    public void generateMethodThatUsesObjectFactory(ClassOutline classOutline) {
        JMethod method = classOutline.implClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC | 
        JMod.FINAL, model.getModel().codeModel.VOID, "useObjectFactory");
        JVar objectFactory = method.param(model.getModel().codeModel.ref(Object.class), "input");
        JExpression objectFactoryCast = JExpr.cast(model.getModel().codeModel.ref("ObjectFactory"), objectFactory);
        JBlock body = method.body();
        //add the objectFactory and objectFactoryCast to the method body
        //...
    }
//...
```

The generated result looks similar to this code:

```
public final static void useObjectFactory(Object input) {
    JAXBElement<SomeType> je = ((ObjectFactory) input).callMethodOfObjectFactory();
    //...
}
```

I don't think this is an ideal approach, but it works. In hope for a better answer at some point in time I won't accept my own answer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You do not iterate over the classes, but over the packages and access the factory via `objectFactory()`.

```java
@Override
public boolean run(Outline model, Options opt, ErrorHandler errorHandler) throws SAXException {
    for (PackageOutline packageOutline : model.getAllPackageContexts()) {
        JDefinedClass factory = packageOutline.objectFactory();
        //factory may be null for empty packages
    }
}
```

Btw, each `ObjectFactory` is created "on the fly" while xjc is processing the xml/json/etc. You need to manually adjust the object factory in case you've made manual type changes in some of your generated `JDefinedClass` classes.